# Plotting line data correctly

Tags: plot, line, display

I am using SBCL Common lisp with Vega Lite.

```
    (defun eod-plot-ticker (item &optional (ndat 100) (par 
       'current-price))
     (let* ((code (eod-search-code item))
     (str (eod-history item ndat))
     (xl (map 'vector 'convert-symbol-yearday
      (map 'vector #'first str)))
     (yl (map 'vector #'cdr str))
     (title (concatenate 'string (string item)
             "   " (string par)))
     (ytitle "value"))
     (plot:plot
     (vega:defplot simple-line-plot
    `(:title ,title
     :width 500
    :height 350   
     :data ,(ls-user::make-df '(:xl :yl) (list xl yl))        
     :mark :line
     :encoding (:x (:field :xl
                     :type :quantitative
                     :title "day date")
                     :y (:field :yl
                     :title ,ytitle
                    :type :quantitative
                    :scale (:domain '(50 100)))))))))
```

The result is a blank display. If I take the domain statement out the data plot regularly but compressed between the 50 and 70 y values. I wish to amplify the data behaviour reducing the y axis interval. What am I doing wrong ?